# HTML5 : Video element without 'src' attribute

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am using one of the webrtc libraries to show video and attaching the stream received to video element. But when I inspect the video element, `src` attribute is missing.

```
<video autoplay="" id="EKA-e2RERLzhCFy8AAEd" class="videoRoom"></video>
```

I have couple of questions here :

1. Is it possible for `video` element to have no `src` attribute.
2. If possible, how to get `src` for that video

Comment: `src` or `source` ?

Comment: <video autoplay="" src="???" id="EKA-e2RERLzhCFy8AAEd" class="videoRoom"></video>

Comment: Please try to keep it to one question per post. --- 1. yes, this can be assigned using JS, although it should show up in dev tools. --- 2. Try `document.getElementById('EKA-e2RERLzhCFy8AAEd').src`

Comment: document.getElementById('EKA-e2RERLzhCFy8AAEd').src produces "" .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible for video element to have no src attribute.

Yes it's possible.

The library you do use probably sets the [`srcObject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject) property of your videoElement.

This property allows to set the source of your video directly to a MediaStream, a MediaSource, a Blob or a File Object.
*Note that FF only supports MediaStreams currently.*

Example for FF (inspect the element afterward)

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true}).then(s=>(vid.srcObject = s));
```

```html
<video id="vid" controls></video>
```

And [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bo5b1qh/) for chrome since it requires `https` protocol for GUM to work.

---

> If possible, how to get src for that video

Well, there is not really an `src` so I'd say not possible.

You can still call `yourVideoElement.srcObject`, but this will return the object to what it was set (usually a MediaStream).
If you need to record it, you can then use a [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder).

Comment: Ya it helps. Can get my work done with srcObject also.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="col-sm-12">
         
        <video width="400" controls>
          <source src="http://ia800803.us.archive.org/17/items/MickeyMouse-RunawayTrain/Film-42.mp4" type="video/mp4">           
        </video>
      </div>
```

In src place the video url you want

```
<video width="400" controls>
    <source src="" type="video/mp4">           
</video>
```